# Pygame bug incremented

Tags: python, pygame

This is a part of my code Python with Pygame Module.

```
gravity = 0.06   
play = 1
while play:
    touch = 0
    while touch == 0:  
        for event in pygame.event.get():
           if event.type == QUIT:
                continuer = 0
            if (event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) and (event.button == 1): 
                y_flappy = y_flappy - 50            
            if (event.type == KEYDOWN) and (event.key == K_UP): 
                y_flappy = y_flappy - 50                 
        y_flappy = y_flappy+gravity  

        fenetre.blit(background,(0,0))    
        fenetre.blit(ground,(0,400))
        fenetre.blit(flappy,(x_flappy,y_flappy))
        pygame.display.flip()
        if y_flappy > 400:
            touch = touch + 1
```

But when y_flappy > 400 , touch is not incremented.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like adding `print("y_flappy: %f  touch: %f" % (y_flappy, touch))` at the end (same indentation level as `if y_flappy > 400:`) to see what happens?

The `touch` variable will not get larger than 1, because then you leave the while loop and reinitialize `touch = 0`.

**Update**

If this still does not work, start with a minimal script like this:

```
y_flappy = 0
gravity = 0.06
play = 1
while play:
    print("Next iteration, reset touch.")
    touch = 0
    print("y_flappy: %f  touch: %f" % (y_flappy, touch))
    while touch == 0:
        y_flappy = y_flappy+gravity

        if y_flappy > 400:
            touch = touch + 1
        print("y_flappy: %f  touch: %f" % (y_flappy, touch))
```

Double check each indentation. You should get the following output:

```
Next iteration, reset touch.
y_flappy: 0.000000  touch: 0.000000
y_flappy: 0.060000  touch: 0.000000
y_flappy: 0.120000  touch: 0.000000
y_flappy: 0.180000  touch: 0.000000
...
y_flappy: 399.960000  touch: 0.000000
y_flappy: 400.020000  touch: 1.000000
Next iteration, reset touch.
y_flappy: 400.020000  touch: 0.000000
y_flappy: 400.080000  touch: 1.000000
Next iteration, reset touch.
y_flappy: 400.080000  touch: 0.000000
...
```

If this works, extend your script line by line to see when it fails.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this. For example when y_flappy is 425.3, touch is 0 (where as it should 1 or more).

Yes i know than touch will not get larger than 1, i can insert break action but it is more simple for me.